# Pivotal tc server is not included in STS 4

Tags: spring-tool-suite, tcserver

I installed STS 4 for windows 10 64bit , and when I tried to create a server then Pivotal is not present ! How to include Pivotal server in STS 4 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three things you need to do:

1.) install the "Pivotal tc Server Integration for Eclipse" extension into your STS4 installation using the Eclipse Marketplace Client.

2.) register and download Pivotal tc Server itself (https://network.pivotal.io/products/pivotal-tcserver)

3.) create a new server instance your STS4 Servers by pointing it to the tc Server install that you have and go from there.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

This is now replaced with "VMware tc Server Integration" Search for this using Eclipse Marketplace