# Spring Tool Suite 4 - is Pivotal tc server deprecated?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, spring-tool-suite, tcserver

I was using STS3 and decided to move to STS4. I got it set up and I imported my projects from the STS3 workspace. These mostly made the transition OK, as I am just learning some basic things, mostly what I have is STS "getting started guides" sorts of projects.

However, I didn't see the default Pivotal tc server in the servers tab, and when I opened the "Define Servers" dialog, "Pivotal tc server" is not available.

Did I miss a step in setting up STS4 or is tc Server no longer the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Spring Tools 4 distribution doesn't include the Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition anymore (as we did with STS3). This doesn't mean at all that the Pivotal tc Server project is deprecated or anything like that. The reason why we don't include that by default anymore is that the Spring Tools 4 are focused on Spring app development using Spring Boot, which usually happens via running the boot apps via the embedded Tomcat option. As a side effect of this, the distribution got smaller and purely open-source... :-)

But those are the only reasons. We still support running Spring Boot applications in locally installed servers like Tomcat or Pivotal tc Server.

Answer (score 0):

Same question asked differently was answered here 
[Pivotal server is not included in STS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148054/pivotal-server-is-not-included-in-sts-4)

Apparently it is no longer bundled by default, but you can install it. I don't think there was any mention of this change in the Pivotal articles about differences between STS3 and 4.